# mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage command will not stop

Tags: java, maven, pittesting

I userd pitest-maven in java maven project ,and when i run "mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage " and wait , i found it will not stop ,and the log output such as :

```
20:38:14 PIT >> FINE : MINION : 2024-01-12 20:38:14.498|INFO |iap|Druid-ConnectionPool-Log-241687404:391|2.0.2.6|7323183788075907206||||||{"url":"jdbc:mysql://7.192.172.28:3306/vmall_iap?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&failOverReadOnly=false&autoReconnectForPools=false&connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=15000&rewriteBatchedStatements=true","dbType":"mysql","name":"DataSource-241687404","activeCount":0,"poolingCount":5,"poolingPeak":5,"poolingPeakTime":"2024-01-12 20:37:22","connectCount":0,"closeCount":0,"keepAliveCheckCount":5}|com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSourceStatLoggerImpl
20:38:19 PIT >> FINE : MINION : 2024-01-12 20:38:19.027|INFO |iap|Druid-ConnectionPool-Log-1272185272:396|2.0.2.6|7323183805297139368||||||{"url":"jdbc:mysql://7.192.172.28:3306/vmall_iap?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&failOverReadOnly=false&autoReconnectForPools=false&connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=15000&rewriteBatchedStatements=true","dbType":"mysql","name":"DataSource-1272185272","activeCount":0,"poolingCount":5,"poolingPeak":5,"poolingPeakTime":"2024-01-12 20:37:26","connectCount":0,"closeCount":0,"keepAliveCheckCount":5}|com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSourceStatLoggerImpl
20:38:54 PIT >> FINE : MINION : 2024-01-12 20:38:54.984|INFO |iap|spectator-poller-0:560|2.0.2.6|7323183959742828998|||||| vertx:   instances:     name       eventLoopContext-created     registry   0     registry-watch 0     transport  0   transport:     server.endpoints:       connectCount disconnectCount rejectByLimit connections requests latency send(Bps) receive(Bps) listen       0            0               0             0           0        0       0         0            127.0.0.1:30888 threadPool:   coreSize maxThreads poolSize currentBusy rejected queueSize taskCount taskFinished name   25       100        0        0           NaN      0         0.0       0.0          cse.executor.groupThreadPool-group1   25       100        13       0           NaN      0         0.0       0.0          cse.executor.groupThreadPool-group0 consumer:  simple:   status      tps      latency            [0,1)  [1,10) [10,100) [100,1000) [1000,) operation               0.0      0.000/0.000        0      0      0        0          0       (summary)  details:     rest.200: producer:  simple:   status      tps      latency            [0,1)  [1,10) [10,100) [100,1000) [1000,) operation               0.0      0.000/0.000        0      0      0        0          0       (summary)  details:     rest.200: |org.apache.servicecomb.metrics.core.publish.DefaultLogPublisher
20:39:14 PIT >> FINE : MINION : 2024-01-12 20:39:14.504|INFO |iap|Druid-ConnectionPool-Log-241687404:391|2.0.2.6|7323183788075907206||||||{"url":"jdbc:mysql://7.192.172.28:3306/vmall_iap?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&failOverReadOnly=false&autoReconnectForPools=false&connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=15000&rewriteBatchedStatements=true","dbType":"mysql","name":"DataSource-241687404","activeCount":0,"poolingCount":5,"poolingPeak":5,"poolingPeakTime":"2024-01-12 20:38:23","connectCount":0,"closeCount":0,"keepAliveCheckCount":5}|com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSourceStatLoggerImpl
20:39:19 PIT >> FINE : MINION : 2024-01-12 20:39:19.029|INFO |iap|Druid-ConnectionPool-Log-1272185272:396|2.0.2.6|7323183805297139368||||||{"url":"jdbc:mysql://7.192.172.28:3306/vmall_iap?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&failOverReadOnly=false&autoReconnectForPools=false&connectTimeout=10000&socketTimeout=15000&rewriteBatchedStatements=true","dbType":"mysql","name":"DataSource-1272185272","activeCount":0,"poolingCount":5,"poolingPeak":5,"poolingPeakTime":"2024-01-12 20:38:27","connectCount":0,"closeCount":0,"keepAliveCheckCount":5}|com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSourceStatLoggerImpl
20:39:54 PIT >> FINE : MINION : 2024-01-12 20:39:54.991|INFO |iap|spectator-poller-0:560|2.0.2.6|7323183959742828998|||||| vertx:   instances:     name       eventLoopContext-created     registry   0     registry-watch 0     transport  0   transport:     server.endpoints:       connectCount disconnectCount rejectByLimit connections requests latency send(Bps) receive(Bps) listen       0            0               0             0           0        0       0         0            127.0.0.1:30888 threadPool:   coreSize maxThreads poolSize currentBusy rejected queueSize taskCount taskFinished name   25       100        0        0           NaN      0         0.0       0.0          cse.executor.groupThreadPool-group1   25       100        13       0           NaN      0         0.0       0.0          cse.executor.groupThreadPool-group0 consumer:  simple:   status      tps      latency            [0,1)  [1,10) [10,100) [100,1000) [1000,) operation               0.0      0.000/0.000        0      0      0        0          0       (summary)  details:     rest.200: producer:  simple:   status      tps      latency            [0,1)  [1,10) [10,100) [100,1000) [1000,) operation               0.0      0.000/0.000        0      0      0        0          0       (summary)  details:     rest.200: |org.apache.servicecomb.metrics.core.publish.DefaultLogPublisher
```

I try again and every result is same ...